# Configure uncrustify to indent c macro

Tags: uncrustify

I rely on `uncrustify` to format C source files and I would like to update from v0.69 to v0.74 but .. I can't get this config consistent:

Let's consider the following example (which is already formatted the way I want it to be):

```c
#if defined(CONFIG_HAS_A)
#define DEVICE_NAME__A_LIST                                                   \
    A1_NAME                                                                   \
    A2_NAME                                                                   \
    ""

#define DEVICE_NAME__A_COUNT                                                  \
    A1_COUNT +                                                                \
    A2_COUNT +                                                                \
    0
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_HAS_B)
#define DEVICE_NAME__B_LIST                                                   \
    B1_NAME                                                                   \
    B2_NAME                                                                   \
    B3_NAME                                                                   \
    ""

#define DEVICE_NAME__B_COUNT                                                  \
    B1_COUNT +                                                                \
    B2_COUNT +                                                                \
    B3_COUNT +                                                                \
    0
#endif
```

Using the version 0.74 of `uncrustify`, the above example code gets formatted to this:

```c
#if defined(CONFIG_HAS_A)
#define DEVICE_NAME__A_LIST                                                   \
    A1_NAME                                                                   \
        A2_NAME                                                                   \
    ""

#define DEVICE_NAME__A_COUNT                                                  \
    A1_COUNT +                                                                \
    A2_COUNT +                                                                \
    0
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_HAS_B)
#define DEVICE_NAME__B_LIST                                                   \
    B1_NAME                                                                   \
    B2_NAME                                                                   \
    B3_NAME                                                                   \
    ""

#define DEVICE_NAME__B_COUNT                                                  \
    B1_COUNT +                                                                \
    B2_COUNT +                                                                \
    B3_COUNT +                                                                \
    0
#endif
```

As you can see, the resulting format for the first define (`DEVICE_NAME__A_LIST`) looks weird and inconsistent compared to the rest of the file ..

What is the right `uncrustify` config option to avoid this?

**NOTE:** I found the `pp_ignore_define_body` option, but it is way too sever as I simply would like the code to be indented one level.

**EDIT:** I found out that some `*_NAME` empty macros cause uncrustify to misbehave right after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the few number of files concerned with this issue I wrapped the concerned macros with  `*INDENT-OFF*` and  `*INDENT-ON*`:

```c
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
#define DEVICE_NAME__A_LIST    \
    A1_NAME                    \
    A2_NAME                    \
    ""
/* *INDENT-ON* */
```

These tags prevent uncrustify from processing the encapsulated content.